# JSP render with two conditions

Tags: jsp, rendering

Is it possible to do something like this?

`rendered="#{kitProduct.productProductCode.serialNumberRequired AND kitProduct.productProductCode.serialNumber != ''}" />`

If so what is the syntax I have all tried && etc. and have had no success with searching.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think `and` operator is `case sensitive`

Try this if used as Deffered Expression:

```
rendered="#{kitProduct.productProductCode.serialNumberRequired 
and kitProduct.productProductCode.serialNumber != ' ' " />
```

Try this if used as Non-Deffered Expression:

```
rendered="${kitProduct.productProductCode.serialNumberRequired 
and kitProduct.productProductCode.serialNumber != ' ' " />
```